# Months Between Two Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a formula you can use to calculate *all* months between two dates. Say the begin date is April 29th and end date is September 1st. Datedif first converts to days and then to months, so it would calculate that there are 125 days or 4.16 months (auto-rounded down to 4). I'm looking for something which counts April, May June, July, August, and September (i.e 6). Is there a formula for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a single cell formula considering also possible year differences:

`=(YEAR(B2)-YEAR(A2))*12+MONTH(B2)-MONTH(A2)+1`

[image]

Comment: Single cell, simple, and always works. Appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula:

```
=DATEDIF(A2,B2,"M")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods:*

[image]

- *Formula for method 1 in cell B75, list of months **includes Start Month**:*

  ```
  =IF(DATE(YEAR($A$75),MONTH($A$75)+ROW(1:1)-1,1)<$A$76,DATE(YEAR($A$75),MONTH($A$75)+ROW(1:1)-1,1),"")
  ```

---

- Formula for method 2:

**Option 1:** If start month is included.

- Formula in cell D75: `=EDATE(A75,0)`
- Formula in cell D76: `=IFERROR(IF(EDATE(D75,1)>$A$76,"",EDATE(D75,1)),"")`

**Option 2:** If start month is excluded.

- Formula in cell  E75: `=EDATE(A75,1)`
- Formula in cell E76: `=IFERROR(IF(EDATE(E75,1)>=$A$76,"",EDATE(D75,1)),"")`

---

**::Edited::**

*You may skip Method 2, and write this formula in cell C75 to get months,  **excludes Start Month**.*

```
 =IF(DATE(YEAR($A$76),MONTH($A$76)+ROW(1:1)-0,1)<$A$77,DATE(YEAR($A$76),MONTH($A$76)+ROW(1:1)-0,1),"")
```

*- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Is there not a formula which does this? I need to do this for *alot* of dates and making a table for each doesnt seem feasible.

Comment: @k.ali ,,, glad to help you ,, since my post has solved the problem then you may accept this as ANSWER as well Up vote [Chek this](https://superuser.com/tour) ☺ For any further assistance pleas write through comments ,,,I'm unable to understand this **Is there not a formula which does this?** !

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`month()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/month-function-579a2881-199b-48b2-ab90-ddba0eba86e8):

`= MONTH("5/4/21") - MONTH("1/3/21")` would yield 4.

You can of course replace the literal inside `month()` with a cell such as:

`= MONTH(A1) - MONTH(A2)`